# JQuery UI Plugin Development - Radio Buttons on a Calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, calendar, radio-button

I'm new to JQuery plugin development. I can make some basic ones involving the html elements however, I want to make one for the DatePicker UI component.

For example, I would like to add some radio buttons onto the date picker. The buttons would allow the user to change the format of the date on the spot.

Does anyone have some advice for me about how to get started on a project like this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, because you're *new to JQuery plugin development* then I could recommend to read the book: [jQuery 1.4 Plugin Development Beginner's Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/jQuery-Plugin-Development-Beginner%2527s-Guide/dp/1849512248/)

There you'll able to edit the existing plugin (for example: calendar-ui).

Also, I could recommend: [jQuery UI Themes Beginner's Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/jQuery-Themes-Beginners-Guide-ebook/dp/B005H0CC8Q/)

By reading books and its example you can learn step-by-step how to develop own plugin for jquery.

Or using [Google](https://www.google.ro/search?q=learn%20jquery%20plugin)